# How to handle thread isolation in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework-6, task-parallel-library

I am working on a multi threaded program, in entity framework, wherein I am facing an issue. I have a list of multiple databases,for each database I need to perform some operations (insert/update), currently I am facing a problem of race condition between thread wherein i am getting error of entity framework.

> Exception: - The underlying provider failed on Open.
>
> InnerException :- The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.

I have used `static readonly object Locker = new object();`

```
lock (Locker)
```

but this will execute thread one by one. Is there any approach where in I can spawn all threads at once, without entity framework error, i.e.,execution in thread isolation.

My Code is as follows

```
var keyController = _empUnitOfWork.Repository<KeyController>()
                                        .Get(x => x.Type.Equals("X") && x.IsOnline).AsNoTracking().ToList();
        var taskList = new Task[keyController.Count];
        for (var i = 0; i < keyController.Count; i++)
        {
            var idx = i;
            var otherUnitOfWork = new TestUnitOfWork(_logger);
            otherUnitOfWork.SetSiteDbContext(_empUnitOfWork, keyController[idx].Id);
            taskList[idx] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                 OtherMethodToBeExecutedOnMultipleThread(keyController[idx], otherUnitOfWork);
            });

        }
        // Wait for all tasks to complete.
        Task.WaitAll(taskList);
```

Comment: I know you're using EF, but at any point are you declaring an `SqlConnection` as a class variable and then reusing it in multiple methods?

Comment: [here](http://programmingencounters.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-use-entity-framework-using-net.html) is some solution.

Comment: Are your variables `_logger` and `_empUnitOfWork` threadsafe? They are potentially used in multiple threads at once.

Comment: Especially `SetSiteDbContext` seems fishy... is that really setting the same `DbContext` to each unit of work?

Comment: You said "execution in thread isolation" which is a weird phrase to me.  A _process_ is the operating system's unit of _isolation_.  A _thread_ is the operating system's unit of _execution_.  If you need isolation, use processes.

Answer (score 0):

Hello all thanks for your responses,
I have found a solution i now initialize new DB context for every thread.It is working as expected and can spawn all threads at once.

Comment: Why are you trying to use EF in multiple threads? It won't make slow queries run faster, it will cause more *locking and contention* on the server. If you have slow queries find ways to fix them by better indexing, *avoid* loading unnecessary data, making aggregations on the server instead of the client.

Comment: If you want to avoid blocking the client, use the asynchronous versions of `ToList()`, `ToArray()` etc, ie `ToListAsync()`, `ToArrayAsync()`

Comment: If you want to load multiple objects *DON'T* execute multiple commands. Write a LINQ query that results in a `ID IN (...)` clause with `myIdList.Contains(myEntity.ID)`.